# Conditional for loop which remembers the iteration number

Tags: python, iteration, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a class with two inputs and one output. The class is called 10 times a second. One of the inputs is a list which does not change with time, but the other input changes with time.

The outputs of this class are the members of the input list.
The class should look like something like this.

```
import lib601.sm as sm

counter = 0
class FollowFigure(sm.SM):
    def __init__(self, waypointsList):
        self.waypoints = waypointsList
    def getNextValues(self, state, inp):
        global counter
        sensors = inp
        current_point = sensors.odometry.point() 

        if counter == 0:
            while not(self.waypoints[0].isNear(current_point, 0.01)):
                return (state, self.waypoints[0])
            counter += 1
        if counter == 1:
            while not(self.waypoints[1].isNear(current_point, 0.01)):
                return (state, self.waypoints[1])
            counter += 1
        if counter == 2:
            while not(self.waypoints[2].isNear(current_point, 0.01)):
                return (state, self.waypoints[2])
            counter += 1                
        if counter == 3:
            while not(self.waypoints[3].isNear(current_point, 0.01)):
                return (state, self.waypoints[3])
```

So the class must check a condition which changes with time, if that condition is not satisfied return inp[0] and wait until it is satisfied and do not check other conditions. if the condition is satisfied for inp1[0] go to the next while, and on the next call of this class do not check the previous while's. I have been thinking on this for the past 5 hours and can not figure out how to solve it. It should not be that hard. Maybe I can not concentrate good enough.

I have tried to write a for loop for this, but since this class is called 10 times each second in some cases it does not have the output it should have, because the iteration is reset each time it is called. BTW this class should work for any finite lenght inp1.

Edit: The above code works good for an input list with 4 elements.

Comment: You need to go back and rewrite your entire method to achieve you goal. Your code is the worst i have ever seen. You never call a while in a procedural style. Not sure why you would want to repetitively return the same value when you could create a function to do it once. Bottom line is, you need to rewrite.

Comment: Keep a list of those items that have passed your condition, then on each iteration check for the ones from the original `inp1` that are not in the "checked" list.

Comment: What I really dont understand is why `while`? If the condition is never met, program will be in infinite loop.

Comment: @RichardGrant If i knew how to write that function I would have written it.

Comment: @thefourtheye Obviously I am a noob. I am just trying to keep it the way I understand it until it works. Then I will try to improve the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Ali Thats okay. But think twice before using `while` for your case.

Comment: Note that all those `while` statements are effectively an `if` statements, since inside there is `return` statement. So it will always break out the loop in at most one iteration (can be 0 if the condition in the while loop is not fulfilled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be writing an application to detect whether someone is walking through a prescribed waypoints in order, by checking their location every 0.1s.

In the code below I assume that each time the function is called, it will return the next checkpoint to be visited. So in the beginning it will return `waypoint[0]`, and sometime later when we reach `waypoint[0]`, the function will return `waypoint[1]`, until we reach `waypoint[2]`.

Your code can be greatly simplified to this:

```
import lib601.sm as sm

class FollowFigure(sm.SM):
    def __init__(self, waypointsList):
        self.waypoints = waypointsList
        self.next_to_visit = 0  # The next waypoint to be visited

    def getNextValues(self, state, inp):
        sensors = inp
        current_point = sensors.odometry.point()
        if self.waypoints[self.next_to_visit].isNear(current_point, 0.01):
            # We reached the next waypoint, go for next waypoint
            self.next_to_visit += 1
        # Return the next waypoint to be visited
        return (state, self.waypoints[self.next_to_visit])
```

Note that there is no `while` loop inside the function. The `return` statement will always return `waypoints[0]` while we have not reached `waypoints[0]`, because `self.next_to_visit` will always be 0 until we reach `waypoints[0]`. So returning `waypoints[self.next_to_visit]` at any function call is performing the required task correctly. =)

Then later you can check whether you have finished all the waypoints by checking whether the value of `self.next_to_visit` equals the length of the `waypoints` list, after we increase `self.next_to_visit`. If it's equal, then we arrived at the final destination already, and you can return the thing accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, and it works. Thanks. I think I did not understand many things in OOP. You have defined self.next_to_visit attribute in __init__  method. As far as I know whenever a class is called the method __init__ will also be called, so the attribute self.next_to_visit will reset to zero each time. 
I have checked it and it does not reset to zero, but I do not understand why. Hum?

Comment: The `__init__` method will only be called when the **instance** of the class is created, not when a **method** of the class is called. You create an instance by calling its constructor like `the_obj = FollowFigure(waypoints)`. That is when `__init__` get called. Then at later time, your application will call the **method** `getNextValues` 10 times a second (like `the_obj.getNextValues(state, inp)`). Since it does not call the constructor `FollowFigure()`, the method `__init__` is not called anymore. So you can put any initialization there (that's why it's called `__init__`, for initialization)